# How to use relational DB with online/offline replica with Electron-Node?

Tags: mysql, node.js, electron, relational-database, desktop-application

I am just starting to use Electron and I have a question about databases. Due to the kind of App I am developing I need a relational DB.

The idea is the user will open the App, if there is connection it would store the data both locally and remotely. If the App is offline it will store the data locally and whenever is online again it will send that data to the remote server. Basically it will be thee same database (local and remote) but it can work offline if necessary.

I am lost on which database will be better for this. As I said I am using MySQL right now and I know you can use MySQL with nodejs so I might give it a try. Also, I am used to use MySQL within a backend language such as PHP, how would you do it in Electron?

Thanks for your time guys!